# Regex that finds consecutive words with first letter capitalized

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that can identify in a sentence that consecutive words in a sentence start with capital letters.

If we take the text below as an example:

> The A-Z Group is a long-established
> market leader in the provision of
> information for the global air cargo
> community, and also for the defence
> and security sectors through BDEC
> Limited, publishers of the British
> Defence Equipment Catalogue and
> British Defence Industry Directory.

I want to be able to retrieve the following:

> The A-Z Group
>
> BDEC Limited Defence Equipment
>
> Catalogue British Defence
>
> IndustryDefence Industry

Is this even possible with a regex?
If so, can anyone suggest one?

Comment: Do you want to match single words, or only two or more?

Comment: can you clarify in your question why in the result, BDEC appears twice?  Also the last few words in the original sentence, shouldn't they appear in the result then?  Also, your first sentence has a "that" which makes the sentence weird. So your emphasis is to find consecutive capitalized words.  The keyword is "consecutive"? (2 or more?)

Comment: What about names like `Pavarotti & Friends` (ampersand instead of "and") or `Lola's Cafe` (the apostrophe for possession)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Update: I misunderstood your question at first.)

A simple case is

```
/([A-Z][\w-]*(\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+)/
```

It may need to be modified if there are special cases of different language construct.

`ruby-1.9.2-p0 > %Q{The A-Z Group is a long-established market leader in the provision of information for the global air cargo community, and also for the defence and security sectors through BDEC Limited, publishers of the British Defence Equipment Catalogue and British Defence Industry Directory.}.scan(/([A-Z][\w-]*(\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+)/).map{|i| i.first}`

`=> ["The A-Z Group", "BDEC Limited", "British Defence Equipment Catalogue", "British Defence Industry Directory"]`

Comment: That only finds capitalized words, not sequences of one or more words like was asked.

Comment: I didn't know the keyword was consecutive... now fixed

Comment: Ruby is the language I am using so this is excellent.  Thanks!!

Comment: Nice job! However, this does not work with special characters (like words with accents). How can I use it without removing special chars from original text?

Answer (score 4):

hopefully this will do what you want, but apologies if I've misunderstood:

```
([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[\s]{0,1}){2,}
```

The regex searches for two or more consecutive occurences of the following sequence: a capital letter followed by any amount of lowercase/uppercase/numerical/hyphen characters (alter this to any range of non-whitespace characters to suit your needs of course), followed by a whitespace character.

Edit: I know it's common sense, but just make sure that you set the regex search to be case sensitive, caught me out when I tested it :p

Edit: The above regex will, as 動靜能量 points out, match the single word THE because it doesn't enforce that at least the first two items must have a space between them. Corrected version:

```
([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)([\s][A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)+
```

Comment: Looks good. A language specific problem though, he will need to match across newlines.

Comment: The answer `([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[\s]{0,1}){2,}` will match a single word `THE` won't it?

Comment: @動靜能量 Thanks for pointing that out, edited my answer to fix that.

Comment: ah i think your newest answer `([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[\s])([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[\s]?)+` will match an extra space at the end

Answer (score 3):

Start off by thinking in non-technical terms. What do you want? A "word" followed by one or more groups of "a word separator followed by a word"

Now you just need to define the pattern for a "word" and a "word separator", and then combine those into a complete pattern.

When you break it down like that, a complex regex is nothing more than a few very simple pattern groups.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mystring = "the United States of America has many big cities like New York and Los Angeles, and others like Atlanta";

@phrases = $mystring =~ /[A-Z][\w'-]\*(?:\s+[A-Z][\w'-]\*)\*/g;

print "\n" . join(", ", @phrases) . "\n\n# phrases = " . scalar(@phrases) . "\n\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ ./try_me.pl

United States, America, New York, Los Angeles, Atlanta

\# phrases = 5
```