# Java - Tokenizing a string based on quotes and capital case

Tags: java, regex, indexing, tokenize

I was wondering what would be a good approach to tokenize a string such as:

```
"'The president' of the United States is Barack Obama"
```

So that it returns:

```
{The president, of, the, United States, is, Barack Obama}
```

Comment: I think you would need a parser to handle this in general.

Comment: What do you want your code to do with _"The president of the United States was Martin van Buren"_?  How about _"The president of Cote d'Ivoire is Alassane Ouattara "_? A general solution to this problem cannot be based solely on capitalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some looking around I managed to get the following regex:

```
([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)([\s][A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)+|'([^']*?)'|[^\s{.,:;”’()?!}]+
```

Which seems to work for my purposes.

Sources: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113082/6601606
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16746437/6601606