# Python RgEx: Extract First Consecutive Capitalized Letters

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I have some news headlines and I would like to extract the name of the company involved in the headline. Here is an example

```
headlines = [
    "Chicago Policemen's Annuity & Benefit Fund hired Chicago Equity Partners to manage $50 million in active U.S. smidcap value equity.",
    "Belmont Contributory Retirement System is searching for at least one U.S. small-cap equity manager to run initially up to $5 million.",
    "Phoenix Employees' Deferred Compensation Board will begin a search for an investment consultant before the end of February."    
]
```

As you can see, the pattern here is that the company name of interest is the first chain of capitalized words. The second chain of capitalized words is the secondary company.

In our example, I want to return two variables all related to extracting the consecutive capitalized letters. So, it would return "Chicago Policemen's Annuity & Benefit Fund", "Belmont Contributory Retirement System", and "Phoenix Employees' Deferred Compensation Board"

Is there a way to do this extraction with regular expressions in Python?

Comment: Shouldn't the first example stop at `Chicago Policemen's Annuity`, though? "&" isn't a capital letter.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post your code and describe what it currently produces versus what you would like for it to produce.  Also, the ampersand `&` is not a capital letter, so that doesn't fit with your described intentions.

Comment: Is `&` a letter though? I'd see it as non-word-fluff separating words.

Comment: Why's everyone so hung up on that ampersand? The OP's intentions are clear, are they not?

Comment: Try [`^(?:(?:[A-Z][a-zA-Z'-]*|&)(?: +|$))+`](https://regex101.com/r/kRFoh0/1)

Comment: @Rawing, because there's a bunch of corner cases hiding behind the ampersand. If a headline reads "Man goes to Burger King & the library", should the output be "Burger King &"? You might be thinking "you could nail down sensible behavior by specifying what should happen in these kinds of cases"; I agree; that's why I'm asking for specifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex that finds consecutive words with first letter capitalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113051/regex-that-finds-consecutive-words-with-first-letter-capitalized)

Comment: @Kevin I think it's reasonable to assume that the output should be "Burger King", as "Burger King &" isn't a company name. And anyway, if you want to know what the expected output of a corner case is, it would be better to ask "What should happen in corner case X?" than to point out that the OP's problem specification is technically not correct.

Answer (score 2):

For your given example, maybe is is an option to match the consecutive capitalized words until you encounter a space and a lower case character or the end of the string.

[`^(?:[A-Z][^A-Z]+?)+(?= [a-z]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Bxkbb1/1)

**Explanation**

- from the beginning of the string `^`
- a non capturing group `(?:`

  - match an uppercase character `[A-Z]`
  - match not an uppercase character one or more times non greedy `[A-Z]+?`
- close capturing group `)+` and repeat one or more times
- a positive lookahead `(?=` which asserts that what follows is

  - a white space followed by a lowercase character `[a-z]`
  - `|` or
  - the end of the string `$`
- close positive lookahead `)`

In this case the matching stops until you encounter a white space and a lowercase character, but you could for example extend the character class to `[a-z&]` to stop matching when you encounter a white space and an ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you in the right direction,

step 1: slice your strings (your delimiter being a space)

step 2: check if the char at position 0 is capitalized

step 3: add/append the sub string to `your company name`

step 4: repeat steps 2 and 3 until step 2 fails, then you have your company name.

More help on slicing:
https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

This regex will find Title-styled expressions:

```
((?:[A-Z][a-z\']+ ?)| & ){2,}(?= \b)
```

You can see a full test [here](https://regex101.com/r/I8Aqhy/3)