# How to make a pattern that check that all the first letter should be capital?

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, pattern-matching

I need a pattern on angular that checks only if the first letter of each word will be capital.
To Make something like this I am using this pattern

```
pattern ="^([A-Z][a-z]*((\\s[A-Za-z])?[a-z]*)*)$"
```

1-works only for the first letter

2- when I have for example 2 fails, I want to check the first letter of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this regex pattern:

```
^(\b[A-Z]\w*\s*)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this regex pattern :

```
/([A-Z][\w-]*(\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+)/
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113070/8090014

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern works only for the first letter in the first word because the word has to start with an uppercase A-Z. But after that, the repeated group starts with `\s[A-Za-z]` which would also match a lowercase a-z.

Note that `\s` also matches a newline. I you don't want that, you could match either a space or tab using a character class `[ \t]`

You could use match starting with A-Z and in the repeated group also start with matching A-Z. If you want to match words, you could use matching a word character `\w`

```
^[A-Z]\w*(?:[\t ]+[A-Z]\w*)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fyCtW9/1)